# Justification in textArea with variable fontSize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a text area which is editable. When we enter text in the `textArea`, the font size of the text change with the change in the text length. The greater the text length, smaller the `font-size`. This causes problems in the justification, is there any way I can justify the text inside the text area.

**Here is the JavaScript Code:**

```
var textie = document.getElementById('new1');
var spanny = document.getElementById('length');
var textLength;
textie.addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
var size;
textLength = textie.value.length;  
size = Change(textLength);
this.style.fontSize = size;
},false);

function Change(fontLength) 
{
var fontSize;
if(fontLength>=1 && fontLength<=4)
{
    fontSize = 35+"px";
}
else if(fontLength>=5 && fontLength<=12)
{
    fontSize = 30+"px";
}
else if(fontLength>=13 && fontLength<=35)
{
    fontSize = 20+"px";
}
else if(fontLength>=36 && fontLength<=50)
{
    fontSize = 18+"px";
}
else if(fontLength>=51 && fontLength<=150)
{
    fontSize = 16+"px";
}
else if(fontLength>150)
{
    fontSize = 15+"px";
}
return fontSize;
}
```

**Here is the HTML**

```
<textArea class = "new" id = "new1"></textArea>
<span id = "length"></span>
```

[I am attaching a jsfiddle, try adding (lots of) random text in it and you will understand](http://jsfiddle.net/ankit90/u69sX/)

Thanks!

Comment: What justification and what problems? There is no attempt at any justification in the code posted.

Comment: Yeah, so is there any way of doing it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are nothing wrong with your script. Actually, TextArea text justifying is not supported by major browsers.

Comment: So, is there no way I can align text in the text area.

Comment: Actually, no. But you can look for alternatives. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427039/justify-text-in-a-html-xhtml-textarea

Comment: thanks for the help, I think its really not possible to justify text in a textArea without using a widget. Thanks though!!