# Justify and Center <textarea> text HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, textarea, center, justify

I have a textarea and I want it to be justified so all the lines are equal in width and to be centered to the text stays in the middle of the textarea when it's not at maximum line length.

This is my textarea:

```
<textarea class="Whiteboard" type="text" placeholder="Type something..."></textarea>
```

...and the CSS:

```
textarea.Whiteboard{
    resize: none;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    border: none;
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Have you tried `text-align: justify;` ??

Comment: @LcSalazar It doesn't center the last line. EDIT-Or the first line if its the only one.

Comment: Tried myself but without success, may be [this][1] will help?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427039/justify-text-in-a-html-xhtml-textarea

Comment: Maybe this will help? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704896/how-to-center-justify-text-in-css

Comment: text-align: justify -> Stretches the lines so that each line has equal width - if there is only one line there is nothing to stretch it against so it works as expected. Same goes for the last line it align the above line with the one underneath.

Comment: You may need to involve higher power to get the result you want

Comment: There is actually a Css Text Level 3 Property called `text-align-last`, that is supposed to change the alignment of the last line of a text... But I couldn't figure it out yet... I think the support is not wide still too.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no concrete CSS solution at the time of writing to achieve the desired result.

However CSS level 3 has introduced a feature under the name `text-align-last` to handle the alignment of the last line of a block:

> **[7.3 Last Line Alignment: the text-align-last property](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text/#text-align-last-property)**
>
> This property describes how the last line of a block or a line right
>   before a forced line break is aligned.

But it is still in *Working Draft* state. Hence the browser support is not good enough to rely on this technology (It's still [buggy on Chrome 35](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=76173) and only works on Firefox 12+).

Here is an **[example](http://jsbin.com/yoyiy/2/edit)** which I'm not able to verify <sup>(because of my FF4. Yes! shame on me)</sup>:

```css
textarea {
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: justify;
    -moz-text-align-last: center; /* Firefox 12+ */
    text-align-last: center;
}
```

Comment: In order to allow to show the new lines you must use '**white-space: pre-line;**' instead of 'white-space:normal;'. See also [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

Answer (score 3):

Alternative: use `contenteditable`

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #eee;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-all;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text" contenteditable=true>click here and edit</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A possible issue with this solution is that it is hard to constrain the height of the editable region in Chrome.If you add more lines, it stretches the text outside of the 150px that you specified. (Firefox does not have this issue).

Comment: @personal_cloud you can add to `.container` class the  `overflow: auto;` to add scrollbars to prevent exceed div height by multilines text

Answer (score -3):

In order to center the textarea element, you have to declare it as a block element in CSS and then add typical centering rules, if necessary.

```css
textarea { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
```

I was looking for an answer to this and could not find out what I was looking for; hence this post.

Comment: refer this first
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score -3):

I know this was 7 years ago. But the short answer is that this works flawlessly

```
text-align: center
```

Comment: this centers horizontally the text but does not justify it.