# Is there any possiblility to justify text in a textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea, text-alignment, justify

i hardly try to justify the text in a textarea in Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

I already tried serveral things. text-align: justify; and white-space: pre-wrap; dont work. Any other white-space-property removes spaces in the textarea.

It´s a totally basic textarea and there are no additional components that influence it.

I really need help i´m working on this since last saturday....

Comment: I have a feeling that trying to use a <textarea> is your problem. Have you tried a <span>, <div>, <p>, table cell, or other text tags?

Comment: Check out this previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21097915/8332308

Comment: Maybe you should try : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LoWGjP and tell us about that great idea of justifying text in an editable text area  ;) Maybe it explains itself why it is not working

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. 
@ developing2020, i already tried that, doesn´t work in Firefox on Mac, it removes the spaces.
@G-Cyr i actually didn´t know that there was the possibility of contenteditable for divs. That actually solved my problem. Thanks a lot! :)